# How to loop through files in a directory multiple times in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to input data from a range of specific files in a large directory into a model written in Python.

To loop through files 1 time I currently do:

```
for i in range(nt):
    streamflow = "streamflow"
    nc = ".nc"
    discharge_filename=[streamflow + `i` +nc for i in range(1000,2000)]
```

Then use each of these files 1 time for every time step in the model. I want to be able to loop through the files more than once, so when I reach, discharge_filename = streamflow2000.nc, I return back to streamflow1000.nc and start over counting until the for loop is finished.

This seems simple but I rarely code in Python and this is really stumping me! Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You should expand on what you're trying to do, and what the value of `nt` is. Also, `range(1000, 2000)` returns `[1000, ..., 1999]`.

Comment: Notice that you actually construct a list of filenames, not a single filename and you do that `nt` times, not once as you mentioned in the question.

Comment: I'm confused, if `nt` = 2 then you will perform two passes on discharge_filename

Comment: + I assume you use Python 2.x, since: "Backticks are a deprecated alias for repr(). Don't use them any more, the syntax was removed in Python 3.0." I had no idea about the backticks a minute ago :D

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to loop over what you've *already* looped over, you need to define an outer loop. The outer loop will define how many times that you'd like your inner loop to run.

For example:

```
for n in range(0,10):
  for o in range(0,10):
    print(n + o)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Chadvandehey's answer is correct - if you want to go over infinite loop just do `while True` or maybe without outer loop at all : just use xrange instead of range and assign value of 0 in the inner loop when `i == nt-1`. use while loop , something like this:

```
 i = 0 
 while i < nt:
    //do whatever you want
    if i == nt-1:
        i=0
```

just be very careful with infinite loops.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.6+ you can use [Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). Creating filenames in a loop can me done in the following way:

```
for i in range(1000, 2001):
    filename = f'streamflow{i}.nc'
    ...
```

Regarding the other answers proposing putting an outer loop around the code above, I think that you actually want to do sth like that:

```
for i in range(1000, 2001):
    filename = f'streamflow{i}.nc'
    # read data

# Some logic here

for i in range(1000, 2001):
    filename = f'streamflow{i}.nc'
    # write data (once to each file)
```

However, if you really want/need to append some data to these files numerous times, just use an outer loop as offered in the other answers.